# Extraer el tipo de un array a un elemento

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, type

me he encontrado con un inconveniente a la hora de usar una libreria externa y es que tiene muchos tipos definidos pero como arrays

```
export declare type ReposListCommitsResponseData = {
    url: string;
    sha: string;
    node_id: string;
    html_url: string;
    comments_url: string;
    // ...
    parents: {
        url: string;
        sha: string;
    }[];
}[];
```

¿Hay alguna forma de extraer el "objeto" sin el array? Es decir:

```
type ReposListCommitsResponseDataElement = {
    url: string;
    sha: string;
    node_id: string;
    // ...
    parents: {
        url: string;
        sha: string;
    }[];
};
```

No quiero dejarlo como tipo `any`.

Estoy generando un archivo propio `index.d.ts` pero creo que no es la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, me resulta raro usar la posición `0` en una definición de tipos

```
import {ReposListCommitsResponseData} from '@octokit/types';

type ReposListCommitsResponseDataElement = ReposListCommitsResponseData[0];
```

[Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type)